# Compare the size of two latest files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have seen a few different ways to compare files, but not exactlly what I am after, what I need to do is a basic file size compare of two files, and if there almost the same it is ok otherwise an error will be sent

I need to have inparameter for errorspan and the catalog they are in.

I would prefer a basic Dos script to run .

input errorspan, catalog

`Find latest local file A
 Find nextlatest remote file B
 If file A and file B is almost the same (errorspan)?
  if not error`

Comment: what means `almost the same` ?

Comment: that would be the errorspan input. Fx. If one file is 1000Mb and the other is 900Mb the errorspan input might be 100MB which means it will be OK

Comment: I've updated the tags on your question under the assumption that you're looking for a solution that will work on modern versions of Windows, and the not an ancient and obsolete 16-bit operating system. If that's not the case and you're actually looking for a solution that works on MS-DOS and not Windows, then you should know Stephan's answer won't work on MS-DOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
REM list files sorted to date and get the sizes of the latest two of them:
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /o-d /b *.*') do (
  set /a i+=1
  if !i! gtr 2 goto :out
  set size!i!=%%~zf
  set name!i!=%%~nxf
)
:out 
echo %name1% = %size1%, %name2% = %size2%
set /a diff=size2-size1
echo Difference: %diff%
```

of course the `name`parts are obsolete (but nice for troubleshooting).