# Batch script - How to zip latest file in directory

Tags: batch-file, backup, archive, 7zip

I'm making a handy dandy little batch file program (partly for fun) that helps me back up my game saves easily. The code I'm using is basically this:

```
"D:\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "destination path" "source path"
```

This has seemed to work great, but is only practical to save games where there is only a single save within a folder or maybe if the name of the save file never changes. This is because if there were several saves in the saves folder like:

```
Save 55
Save 54
Save 53
```

Then it would add all of them to the archive instead of just the latest one like I want. So my question is how can I only archive the latest file in these cases. Or the file with greatest number in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Using my limited coding knowledge and answers from the helpful users that responded, I was able to come up with a satisfactory answer to my question:

1 `@echo off`

2 `set "latest=ERROR: No latest file found!"`

3 `set "name=WARNING unnamed Backup Archive"`

4 `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /od "source path"') DO set "latest=%%a" & set "name=%%~na"`

5 `echo Latest save file: %name%`

6 `"D:\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "destination path\%name%.7z" "source path\%latest%"`

7 `pause`

My (rudimentary) understanding of this line by line goes as follows:

Lines 2-3 The second and third lines are like creating string variables named "latest" and "name" which will later get changed into the name of the latest file in the source directory.

Line 4 The `for /f` command goes through all the files (I think) in the source directory and eventually changes "latest" and "name" to be the name of the newest file it found. `/b` makes it output only brief file names instead of including a bunch of other info and `/od` sorts the files by date. "source path" is the path of the directory containing files to be backed up. "latest" gets set to `%%a` which will be the name of the newest file and "name" gets set to the same thing but with `~n` which removes the file type at the end.

Line 6 This is what actually archives it. The first part is the path for the 7zip.exe. `a` is the command to make an archive. Next is the destination path with "name" and finally the source path with "latest". The reason why I have both latest and name is because the program was outputting an archive with the file type in the name. For example File.txt.7z. I couldn't just use ~n for the source on line 6 because it wasn't working so that's why I needed to make both.

I'm sure this explanation sounds painful to someone who knows what they're doing but hopefully it can be helpful to another novice like me. Also be sure to look at the other responses as they know what they're doing much better than me.

Comment: That's not what I would call "rudimentary understanding". It's accurate and well explained (the `%%~` modifiers only work within the `for` loop). You may want to include a line 5.5 `if "%latest% =="ERROR: No latest file found!" ( echo %latest% & pause & goto :eof )`

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by "greatest number" does not work (`5` is bigger than `20`, due to strict string comparison), so I'l focus on "latest write access", which will also work when the game has several "save slots" and you might save with "slot 3` (not the highest number, but the latest gamesave)

`dir` has an option to sort files by time: `/o-d` sorts newest files first, `/tw` sets the sort criteria to "last write access" (see `dir /?` for more information). Use a `for /f` loop to capture the output (see `for /?`):

```
@echo off
set "latest="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /tw /o-d "save*"') do if not defined latest set "latest=%%a"
echo latest save game: %latest%
```

Comment: As a side note, when you use `-D` or `D` with `/O`, internally `/T` with `W` is the default order, therefore you'd only need to use the `/T` option if you wanted it ordering by the Last Access, `A`, or Creation, `C` date/time stamp.

Comment: So I was able to come up with this and it seems to work:

`@echo off
set "latest=No matching file found"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /od /B "save path\*"') DO set "latest=%%a"
echo Latest save game: %latest%
pause`

`/o-d` wasn't working so I switched it to `/od`. However `/o-d` works when I do:

`@Echo off
dir /o-d /B "save path\*"
pause`

So Idk why that is

`/B` displays a bare list of directories and files, with no additional information

My question now is how do I get the TWO latest files instead of just the latest one. Some games break their saves into multiple files

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29119145/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

There could be used the following batch file for this simple task if the batch file is in the directory with the `Save` files of the game.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0Save *" /A-D /B /O-D 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V ".zip"') do "D:\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -bd -bso0 -tzip -mx9 -y "destination path\%%~nI.zip" "%~dp0%%I" & goto EndBatch
echo Could not find any "Save *" file!
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

`%~dp0` is expanded to full path of the batch file always ending with a backslash. If the batch file should use the **current directory** as source directory instead of the batch file directory, just remove all `%~dp0`. If the batch file should use a specific source directory, replace all `%~dp0` by the source directory path ending with `\`.

`destination path\` must be adapted to whatever is wanted as destination directory path which can be also `%~dp0` to reference the directory containing the batch file.

There is executed in background one more `cmd.exe` with option `/c` to run its internal command **DIR** to search in the specified directory for files matching the wildcard pattern `Save *` and to output just the names of the found files without path in order from newest to oldest according to last modification time. This list of file names is redirected to **FINDSTR** which filters out case-insensitive all file names ending with the file extension `.zip` in case of the ZIP files are created also in the directory as the `Save` files.

The newest `Save *` file not having the file extension `.zip` is compressed with 7-Zip using the ZIP compression format with best compression without any output, except an error occurs like the file to compress cannot be read at the moment. Then the batch file processing continues below the label `EndBatch` which means the other file names output by **DIR** are ignored for further processing.

An information message is output if there could not be found any `Save` file in the specified directory by **DIR**.

The ZIP file is created with the name of the `Save` file compressed into the ZIP file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|`must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

See [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.